# Getting a value error Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [2, 16773] when trying to fit data to model

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, train-test-split, model-fitting

I have a data set of domains and urls, and a column of targets, which is a number from 0 : 25.

The domain and urls are the features, and the target column is the y

I read the data using pandas, and then I use `train_test_split` to split the data.

Once I do that, i pass the training data to the model using the `.fit` function.

However, this gives me the error `ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [2, 16773]`

My code is shown below:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer, TfidfVectorizer,

df = shuffle(pd.read_csv(os.path.join(PATH_DATA_TRAIN, 'train.csv')).dropna())
features = ['domain', 'urls']
X = df[features]
y = df[['target']]
# y = df['target] 
# y = y.values.reshape(-1, 1)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_split = 0.2)
clf = Pipeline([
     ('vect', CountVectorizer(stop_words = 'english')),
     ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
     ('clf', RandomForestClassifier()
)])

clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

I followed some suggestions online, and tried to re shape the values of y, but nothing worked.

Below are the shapes of the dataset

```
print(X.shape, y.shape) # (22365, 2) (22365, 1)
print(X_train.shape, y_train.shape) # (16773, 2) (16773, 1)
print(X_train.shape[0] == y_train.shape[0]) # True

# if I use y = df['target'] instead of y = df[['target']], the only difference is shows below. But I still get the same error:
print(y.shape) # (22365,)
print(y_train.shape) # (16773,)
```

Any idea why i keep getting `ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [2, 16773]`?

Comment: Remove one bracket.. Can you try? only change this code and run:    y = df['target']

Comment: @TornikeKharitonishvili I did that initially, and added the results above. There is no difference, still get the same error. if we use one bracket, its no difference. still the same error

Comment: please write both error. also you can change and run:  train_test_split(X, y.value, test_split = 0.2)   __this code try both code: y = df[['target']] and y = df['target']

Comment: As i mentioned, theres no difference between using `y = df[['target']]` and `y = df['target']`. Both give the same error. Also using `train_test_split(X, y.value, test_split = 0.2)` changes nothing. I am still getting the same error: `ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [2, 16773]`